# Perl: Remove list <ul> from paragraph. HTML parsing

Tags: html, perl, parsing

I have a bunch of html files from which i need to extract the text, but not the contents of the lists.
the html is like

```
<html>

    <Head>
        <title>intranet mycompany</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>blah</div>
        <p>the text i need to extract
            <br>
            <ul>
                <li>stuff i don't want.</li>
                <li>more stuff i don't want.</li>
            </ul>More text i need to exctract.</p>
    </body>

</html>
```

I would realy like some advice on how to get the text from the paragraph, but not the text from the list . Any advice would be apriciated.

Regards,
Jombo.

Comment: By the way, that's not HTML. In HTML, a UL element cannot appear inside of a P element.

Comment: @casperOne - When you (as moderator) delete other answer(s), please be so nice and add a comment to that answer with EXACT reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

```
use strictures;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath qw();
my $dom = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_content(q(<html> … </body>));
my ($ul) = $dom->findnodes('//ul');
$ul->delete;
my $extract = $dom->findvalue('//p');
# " the text i need to extract  More text i need to exctract. "
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at CPAN for **HTML Parsers**, you will get nice parsers, like [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aTreeBuilder), [HTML::Parser](http://p3rl.org/HTML%3a%3aParser) etc.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. Can anybody supply some sample code? I am able to get the contents of the paragraph. but the list will still be in it.

Comment: @user1343861 - Just search (right upper corner) for "[perl] HTML parser" and you will find a lot of information here on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get rid of the `<ul>` data. Since HTML::Parser doesn't know where in the document it is when calling the text handler, you have to find some way to give it that info.

Just tell the `start_handler` that is called for each starting element to make a note about an openend `<ul>` and have the `end_handler` remove that note. You can then utilize the information inside your `text_handler` so it can skip over text nodes that are inside of `<ul>s`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use HTML::Parser;

my $text = '';
my $parser = HTML::Parser->new(
  start_h => [ \&start_handler, "self,tagname" ],
  end_h   => [ \&end_handler,   "self,tagname" ],
  text_h  => [ \&text_handler,  "self,dtext" ],
);

sub start_handler {
  my ($self, $tag) = @_;
  $self->{_private}->{'ul'} = 1 if ( $tag eq 'ul' ); # make a note
}

sub end_handler {
  my ($self, $tag) = @_;
  $self->{_private}->{'ul'} = 0 if ( $tag eq 'ul' ); # remove the note
}

sub text_handler {
  my ($self, $dtext) = @_;
  unless ($self->{_private}->{'ul'}) {
    # only if we're not inside the <ul>
    $text .= $dtext;
  }
}
$parser->parse_file('test.html');
print $text;
```

Comment: How about nested ul ?? I would just change the "= 1" and "= 0" to "++" and "--"

Comment: You're right. I forgot that. It should be ``$self->{_private}->{'ul'}++ if ( $tag eq 'ul' );`` and ``$self->{_private}->{'ul'}-- if ( $tag eq 'ul' );`. Thank you.

Answer (score -4):

The hardest bit is that the data is over multiple lines. If you were to join all the lines into one big string, a simple regex like

```
s/<ul>.*<\/ul>//g
```

Should do it.

Comment: This is not a good advice to use regex for parsing _HTML_.Use existing CPAN modules.

Comment: Never parse XML/HTML/CSV files using regex. Use the existing modules, they are usually mature, stable and well tested.

Comment: @briandfoy: It very much works for the example, if you follow the instructions of *"If you were to join all the lines into one big string"*. (In single-line mode, though, it works just as well: http://codepad.org/Wy2iKg5x)

Comment: I agree that if you want to parse HTML, regex isn't the way to go, but if you need a quick and dirty way to get rid of some part of a file, learning a HTML parser may not be efficient use of time.

Comment: @minitech if there is more than a single ul in the data then you will remove everything between the start of the first one and the end of the last one. So it does work for the example provided, which as only 1 ul, but it most likely would not work on real data (note that the beginning of the post states "the contents of the lists", I see enough plurals here to suggest that more than 1 list is indeed a possibility ;--).

Comment: The lines already are one big string. Do you have some system where you can't have newlines in a string?

Comment: @mirod: Okay, and we all accept that regular expressions are not the answer for parsing HTML - but I was just saying that it does actually work for the example, contrary to what brian d foy said.